# Does belongsTo create an instance of the corresponding class?

Tags: grails, belongs-to

I have the following:

```
class Book
{
  static belongsTo = [cart: Cart]
}
```

When I instantiate Book, does it automatically create an instance of Cart and then attach book to it?

Comment: Nope, you have to attach book to cart class as cart class is the owner class.
When you instantiate Book like this:

Book bookInstance = new Book()
then you have to associate bookInstance.cart = cartInstance// where cartinstance may be some existing cart object, or a new one but you have to create it.
Not sure if this is what you are looking for, if you elaborate your question a bit more, or what type or programming issue you have then it will be more helpful.

Comment: Nope this is exactly what I wanted, you should awesome the question with this, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates a field in the class of type `Cart` with name `cart`, as if you had this in your source code:

```
class Book {
   Cart cart
   static belongsTo = [cart: Cart]
}
```

It's a persistent property, like `String title`, etc. But since its type is another domain class it's loaded lazily by default (you can configure this in the mapping or per-query). So loading a `Book` instance doesn't load its owning `Cart` instance, but when you reference one of the `cart` field's properties, it will lazily load.

Additionally, since you've declared a belongs-to relationship, when you delete a `Cart`, all of its `Book`s will be deleted too.